# xcode iPhone app background colour is different to iPad background colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

In my application I use one storyboard for both iPhone and iPad, however when I look at the application on a device for some reason the background colour on the ipad isn't coming out. See images.

iPhone Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOI5g.png

iPad Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SYuh.png

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Share some code. otherwise its hard to get any clue. Share the part where you are setting background color.

Comment: Hi Rashad, I have done all the background through the storyboard interface builder so no code to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by the following code.

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) \
[UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >>  8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)((rgbValue & 0x0000FF) >>  0))/255.0 \
alpha:1.0]

cell.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(HEXCODE);
```